# Reuse variable of older node in xsl in next nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with a bill of material that I have to convert into a text file for further processing. The xml file has a method that if in a Line node Quantity = 0 and Component is empty then the value of Parent should be used for the next coming lines until the next Parent line is found. In those component lines, the value of Parent has to be skipped.

I am struggling with variable or param to store the value of @Parent for further processing. xslt does not support this I found out ;-)

Can someone give me a hint of how to process this xml file? What method I can use? I read a lot already of named templates with params and recursive processing but I fail to find the correct way for my case.

I tried it with a for-each loop and was able to store it in a variable.

Example very simplified input XML

```
<Page>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Component></Component>
    <Parent>ParentID1</Parent>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
    <Component>ComponentID1</Component>
    <Parent>YYY</Parent>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Component>ComponentID2</Component>
    <Parent>ZZZ</Parent>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Component></Component>
    <Parent>ParentID2</Parent>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Component>ComponentID4</Component>
    <Parent>AAA</Parent>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Component>ComponentID5</Component>
    <Parent>XXX</Parent>
  </Line>
<Page>
```

Edit: The answers are helping a lot but the real XML is more complex. I added it here below. The method I used in the beginning is to first setup a variable but it is not working in the for-each-group.

```
<xsl:variable name="EPBomQty" >
 <xsl:for-each select="Label/Property">
        <xsl:if test="PropertyName='Quantity'">
            <xsl:value-of select="PropertyValue"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:variable>
```

new xml

```
<Page>
  <Line>
    <Label source_id="1">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>0</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue/>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ParentID1</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Label source_id="2">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>4</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ComponentID1</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>YYY</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Label source_id="3">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>2</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ComponentID2</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ZZZ</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
  <Line>
      <Label source_id="4">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>0</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue/>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ParentID2</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
  <Line>
     <Label source_id="5">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>3</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ComponentID4</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>AAA</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Label source_id="6">
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Quantity</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>2</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Component ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>ComponentID5</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
        <Property FormattingType="0" FormattingLength="32" FormattingRAlign="1">
            <PropertyName>Parent ID</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>XXX</PropertyValue>
        </Property>
    </Label>
  </Line>
</Page>
```

Expected output for example xml (header can be discarded)

```
#Parent~Component~Quantity
ParentID1~ComponentID1~4
ParentID1~ComponentID2~2
ParentID2~ComponentID4~3
ParentID2~ComponentID5~2
```

Comment: Various answers suggest treating this as a grouping problem, but another way to do it is, when you're processing each line, use `preceding-sibling::Line[Quantity=0 and Component=''][1]/Parent` to get the appropriate `Parent` value.

Comment: @MichaelKay But the question is how to avoid the repetitive lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2/3 alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="Page">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-starting-with="Line[Quantity = 0 and not(normalize-space(Component))]">
         <xsl:value-of select="tail(current-group())/string-join((current()/Parent, Component, Quantity), '~')" separator="&#10;"/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7c

Comment: Hello Martin, I am back from holiday and trying to implement your emthod. But as the input XML is more complex than I first mentioned I still fail. Could you please have another look?

Comment: @WaltervL, consider to ask a new question with your attempt to adatp the suggestions made here to the more complex input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="cpmt" match="Line[Component/text()]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Line[not(Component/text())][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/Page">
    <xsl:for-each select="Line[not(Component/text())]">
        <xsl:variable name="parent" select="Parent" />
        <xsl:for-each select="key('cpmt', generate-id())">
            <xsl:value-of select="$parent"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Component"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have left out the `Quantity = 0` requirement; if it's crucial, you can add it to the predicates.

---

If your processor supports  XSLT 2.0, then this can be much easier using `xsl:for-each-group`:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/Page">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-starting-with="Line[not(Component/text())]">
        <xsl:variable name="parent" select="Parent" />
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$parent, Component, Quantity" separator="-"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To handle your "more complex" input, try:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/Page">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Line/Label" group-starting-with="Label[not(Property[PropertyName='Component ID']/PropertyValue/text())]">
        <xsl:variable name="parent" select="Property[PropertyName='Parent ID']/PropertyValue" />
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$parent, Property[PropertyName='Component ID']/PropertyValue, Property[PropertyName='Quantity']/PropertyValue" separator="-"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I am back from holiday and trying to implement your method. But as the input XML is more complex than I first mentioned I still fail. Could you please have another look?